# springloaded- reloading of classes not happening

Tags: spring, hotswap, spring-loaded

I was going through [spring documentation for reloading classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html) without restarting containers, but when I am trying to do the same by adding springloaded dependency reloading isn't happening, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

i have added spring dev-tools dependency but hot swap wasn't happening, it was problem with intellij. When I tried same in eclipse it worked fine